# Text appearing as symbols after opening Map Package from ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, font, map-package

I am using ArcMap 10.6.1.

Text in my map packages does not export/open correctly.  I have no problem creating  or sharing the map, but when someone else opens the map package the text appears as symbols.  This happens with different fonts.

Any help?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are using a font that is not available on their machine.

Comment: That was what I thought, but it has happened with different standard fonts. The image is from a class project.  The TA said they had no idea why it did that and that they hadn't seen it with anyone else's work.

Comment: What were the precise and detailed steps that you used to create and transfer that map package, and for it to be extracted?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/205834/28687

Comment: Thanks PolyGeo and fatih_dur